# Is there any way to makemigration on a pre-existing docker database?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I have a pre-existing docker container with a postgres database that I'm connecting to my django app, but when I try to "makemigrations" and "migrate" it doens't affect the container. Any clue how I can do it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you point the DATABASES setting in settings.py to the container?

Comment: yes. I'm able to use the database but if I make a change to the models and I want to apply the changes I can't 
```python
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'database',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '172.17.0.2',
        'PORT': '5432',

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running the migration commands from a container or locally?

Comment: I have tried from the entrypoint.sh and locally

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: I just tried from the container and didn't work neither. I don't get any error. but when I inspect the database using pgAdmin I don't see the changes reflected on the database. Beware that the database is on a separate container that is always running, so the only container that I "rebuild" and re-run is the django container.

Comment: "makemigrations" doesn't affect the database. That's what "migrate" does. makemigrations creates the migration files, and should be run in your development environment with the resulting files committed to source control.

Comment: Yes. but I'm doing "migrate" command after "makemigrations" command and it's not working